# Java HTTP Server - com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer vs WebServers such as Jetty or Tornado?

Tags: java, http, servlets, httpserver

I need to develop a Java HTTP Server that processes multiple and in paralell POST/GET Requests from multiple gps devices (not web browser requests).

What is the difference between implementing a HTTP Server using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer and using one of the multiple available pre-coded webservers (like Jetty, Tornado and Simple)?

http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers

Comment: "implementing" vs. "pre-coded". I think you answered a large portion of your own question in the question.

Comment: @rmlan, :P. Thanks for answering. But what more a solution like Jetty can give in consideration to a sun java in-built HttpServer? In my case is a very simple HTTP server, it has nothing to do with web browers. Its a large set of devices sending to my server gps information. Which of these solutions would you choose? And Why?

Comment: Implementing your own might lead to a more lightweight solution, but you will miss out on a lot of the robust features that the other projects might give you (security is the biggest one that comes to mind). If you truly only need a very simple http server with a couple of operations, perhaps your own implementation is the way to go.

Comment: @rmlan thank you so much for your answer. I think I will choose my own implementation (HttpServer) because the only thing more complicated is the multithread issue, that HttpServer solves by using an executor with a threadpool. Security might be important if the requests were made through a webside. But in my case its a closed environment with no or little exterior interaction.

Comment: @rmlan  My other issue, is with the need to parse the incoming requests, but for now they come as a text. Maybe if it was in another format, like XML or Json, maybe then go to a Jetty-like solution? Is there any good webserver with multithread?

Comment: All of the web server implementations you mentioned (and all of the popular ones) will be multithreaded and manage their own thread pools. You could technically still do your own implementation using a data format like XML or JSON, but you would most-likely want to introduce a library to help you with databinding in that case (JAXB for XML, which is included with Java from 1.6 on, and Jackson or GSON for JSON)

Comment: Tk you so much. I will use all that info while implementing a solution. Thank you for your time. It helped me organize things.